Unity LevelPlay - Getting errors when building the project after adding AdMob through LevelPlay
After I added Admob I keep getting these 3 build errors:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-33\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-34\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-33\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-34\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\mtryb\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e89a518bc60f48f1eb49fc28c8025379\jetified-play-services-ads-lite-23.3.0\AndroidManifest.xml:90:9-92:62: AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

0x00007ff629f7fedd (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff629f86c59 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff62af28ba3 (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff62b5cfd13 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff628feb726 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000023cb6f174d3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x0000023cb6f173eb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x0000023cb6f17130 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x0000023cb6f17055 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x0000023b07cb1633 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
0x0000023cb6f028f3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
0x0000023b07c943e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
0x0000023afea9a24b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
0x0000023afea99958 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x0000023afea99c85 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffca73bfee4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffca72feb14 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffca72fecac (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff629ea4ba4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff629e9f6a4 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff62b945911 (Unity) CallMono
0x00007ff62b94d817 (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x00007ff62b94870f (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild
0x00007ff62b9467ee (Unity) DoBuildPlayer
0x00007ff62b93a6b3 (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x00007ff62976cd29 (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00007ff62946e695 (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x0000023cb69e3c87 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
0x0000023cb69e34a3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
0x0000023cb69cfe33 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
0x0000023cb69ba76b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x0000023cb69a93bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x0000023cb699680b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
0x0000023cabda5a2a (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x0000023cabda5843 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
0x0000023cabd96a0b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
0x00000239110da257 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x0000023cabd81e8b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x0000023cb58d64fb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
0x0000023cb58d6363 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
0x0000023cb58d5eab (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x0000023cb58d5d93 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
0x0000023c68edeed3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000023c68edee23 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ExecuteDefaultActionAtTarget (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000023c68edea78 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000023c68ede78f (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000023c68ede4e3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
0x0000023cb58d3153 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000023c69f46e2e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x0000023c69f466fb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000023c68ec931b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x0000023c68ec9183 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
0x0000023c68ec90bb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x0000023c69f46bd3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x0000023c69f461b3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x0000023c69f4602b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x0000023c8bc68b3b (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
0x0000023c8bc684f3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x0000023c8bc682af (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x0000023c8bc681cb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
0x0000023c8bc6801d (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x0000023c8bc680d6 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr& (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ffca73bfee4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffca72feb14 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ffca72fecac (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff629ea4ba4 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff629e9f6a4 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff629e99015 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff629fc9afa (Unity) Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff62a998dc6 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff62af59013 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00007ff62a998bd5 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00007ff62af59f40 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff62af536b9 (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007ffd2fc9ef5c (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007ffd2fc9e684 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff62af2e683 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff62af335e4 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff62c27fc8e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffd2f317374 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffd300bcc91 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart


CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\mtryb\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e89a518bc60f48f1eb49fc28c8025379\jetified-play-services-ads-lite-23.3.0\AndroidManifest.xml:90:9-92:62: AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-33\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-34\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-33\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-34\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:IronSource.androidlib:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageDebugAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processDebugResources FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeDebugNativeLibs
41 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 38 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <db0dda776b294a2499531ff357e9baa7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <9f23e2baa79f4ca28f8464512e06b154>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I'm using Unity version 2022.1.0f1 but have tried 2022.3.47f1 and 6000.0.20f1, in case it was an issue with versions but still had errors. I have the newest version of Unity Plugin (8.3.0).
Any help would be greatly appreciated~!
I've tried looking online for help through googling, chatgpt and discords but without any luck on correctly solving it. I have tried removing property found in manifest manually and adding code to ignore it when built but it doesn't work.
